# Why doesn't myIntArray=Null cause the original data set to get deleted?

Tags: java, arrays

I don't get it. Why is it that when I put myIntArray=null. It doesn't necessarily delete the data on the original myIntArray? Yet mySecondArray would still point back to the original data set of myIntArray.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Answer (score 1):

`myIntArray` and `mySecondArray` both *"point"* to the same data. 
 
After `myIntArray = null`, `myIntArray` does not *"point"* to that data. 
But `mySecondArray` still does. 
The assignment of `null` to an object does not delete any data. 
It just makes that object *"pointing"* to *nothing*.